How to use Vertex Painting to create Subsurface Scatter in specific areas in Blender 4.1?
So I'm new to Blender modelling and am watching tutorials from Dikko on how to create Stylised Characters where I am to apply Subsurface Scatter on the character  and just realised a lot of them are a few years old and are using Blender 3.6 which had since changed the Subsurface Features after 4.0...

The video:
https://youtu.be/gkLFKEvqpP8?t=671&feature=shared
This tutorial I've been following uses a Color Attribute (Vertex Color) canvas to paint a black and white reference of the areas he wants to add Noise to by connecting that and a Color Ramp to the 'Subsurface Value' and then creating a Subsurface Scatter in that highlighted areas.
I'm aware Blender 4.0 made the Subsurface Scattering correspond directly with the Base Color which apparently makes sense to some users but I can't seem to apply it to certain areas like the way he tries to.
Is there a method for applying Subsurface Scattering over Vertex Paint Attributes in 4.0 or is there a better way that I'm unaware of?
Youtube and Stack Overflow all seem to have tutorials of this topic from 2 years ago so I hope I can get some insight...


You can plug the attribute values into the Weight input of the SSS section.

Thanks for your answer!
Took a while for me to realise that I had to increase the 'scale' for it to be visible on larger areas with more vertices.
